# ASP.NET MVC FX sending error message string to another action method not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm catching an error in an action method as there are currently a couple different things that could go wrong (working on it). There are a number of people testing the app and I'd like them to be able to see the exact error. Here is the try block in the action method for creating a new employee:

```
try
{
    db.Employees.Add(employee);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
            var err = validationError.ErrorMessage;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("err: " + err);
            RedirectToAction("ErrorMessage", new { message = err });
        }
    }
}
```

This does successfully print the error message to my console in Visual Studio but it does not redirect the user to the ErrorMessage screen. Rather, the catch block simply moves on. I do not want this to happen.

Any time an error occurs I want the error message to be saved to the string err and then sent to the Error Message page.

#### ErrorMessage Action Result

```
public ActionResult ErrorMessage(string message)
{
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = message;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error message: " + message);
    return View(message);
}
```

What do I need to change?

EDIT: Based on the first answer I added the return (my mistake) but I'm still not redirected to the correct error page. Instead I am directed to this:

[image]

This is the try/catch block now:

```cs
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    var err = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
            err.AppendLine(validationError.ErrorMessage);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("err: " + err);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ErrorMessage", new { message = err.ToString()});
}
```

EDIT 2:

This is what I have right now:

```cs
try
{
    db.Employees.Add(employee);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    var err = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
            err.AppendLine(validationError.ErrorMessage);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("err: " + err);
            return RedirectToAction("ErrorMessage", "Employees", (object)err.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Which actually does redirect me to the `ErrorMessage.cshtml` page. However, I'm not quite sure how to retrieve `(object)err.ToString()` on the ErrorMessage ActionResult. This is what I am trying right now:

```
public ActionResult ErrorMessage(object err)
{
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = err.ToString();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error message: " + err.ToString());
    return View(err);
}
```

And the actual view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ErrorMessage";
}

<h2>Error message page.</h2>

<p>@ViewBag.ErrorMessage</p>
```

But it simply gives me `System.Object` instead of the actual error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to return result object to be able make the `RedirectToAction()` working:

```
var err = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
{
    foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
    {
        Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
        err.AppendLine(validationError.ErrorMessage);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("err: " + err);  
    }
}
return RedirectToAction("ErrorMessage", (object)err.ToString());
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense thank you so much! However, I get this error on the "\n" ````The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer````.

Comment: @GrillOwner69420: Fixed - it was a typo error. Fixed by using the `AppendLine()`;

Comment: Ok that took care of that error but I'm still not being redirected correctly. I updated my question to show what is happening.

Comment: @GrillOwner69420: Sure. The 'message' parameter is declared as a string. Therefore fixed to `return RedirectToAction("ErrorMessage", (object)err.ToString());`

Comment: Ok no error screen now, it just ignores the error and moves on to the next page :/

Comment: @GrillOwner69420: Does the `return RedirectToAction("ErrorMessage", (object)err.ToString());` redirect to the `ErrorMessage()` action method?

Comment: No it isn't. The program simply acts as though the error never occurred. However the print statements still print the correct errors.

Comment: @GrillOwner69420: Hmmm... It's working in my test. Try to use `return new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { {"Controller", "Home"}, {"Action", "ErrorMessage"}, {"message", err.ToString()} });`, instead of `return RedirectToAction("ErrorMessage", (object)err.ToString());`. Just replace the `Home` by your controller name.

Comment: Hey I got it to work using this ````return RedirectToAction("ErrorMessage", "Employees", (object)err.ToString());```` . I'm not sure what was wrong yesturday but it is working great now! However, how do I retrieve the ````(object)err.ToString()```` on the ErrorMessage action view? I updated my question to show you what's going on.

Comment: @GrillOwner69420: Great! When you pass the parameter `(object)err.ToString()` to a view it is necessary to define the model as `@model System.String` (_similar any data model passed to the strongly typed view_) and view is become  `strongly typed`. Therefore you can use `<p>@Model</p>` instead of `<p>@ViewBag.ErrorMessage</p>`. BTW, instead of pass all error messages as one string to the view you can create a list of strings. It will help to display the information in more readable way, without splitting the strings back, and pass the list to the view.

Comment: that still isn't working. I don't think the error message is being sent properly. The URL should be Employees/ErrorMessage?err but it is Employees/ErrorMessage?Length=81. Also, whenever I print err in the ErrorMessage ActionResult it is always null.

Comment: I got it to work like this! ````return RedirectToAction("ErrorMessage", new { message = err.ToString() } );```` ````public ActionResult ErrorMessage(string message)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = message;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error message: " + message);
            return View();
        }```` Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @GrillOwner69420: Actually you did the same. You are welcome!